# Power Series Convergence from Terms

Tags: power-series

My homework wants me to find the interval of convergence and the radius of the power series, but it does not give the function, instead it gives the first 4 terms of the series.

The terms are $-x^{9} + \frac{x^{11}}{8} - \frac{x^{13}}{27} + \frac{x^{15}}{64}$

I am confused on how to accomplish this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you should see some regularities which enable you to "guess" all the other terms. It is not mathematically strict, but hey, it's your homework:

1. First, you should see that your series is alternating
2. Next, notice that the power of $x$ is always increased by 2
3. Finally notice that denominator is always $\frac{1}{n^3}$

So your series is 
$$
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (-1)^n \frac{x^{7+2n}}{n^3}
$$